# Get offset of node within rapidjson?

Tags: c++, json, c++11, rapidjson

I am deserializing a json string into an object using rapidjson.   When I encounter an issue, not with the structure of the json, but with the content, I want to report an error stating the offset of where the problem is.

Unfortunately, unless it is a  parse error, I don't see where I can get the current offset of a Value within a Document.   Anyone have any ways of accomplishing this?

For example:

```
Document doc;
doc.Parse<0>(json.c_str());
if( doc.HasMember( "Country" ) ) {
    const Value& country_node = doc["Country"];
    if( !isValid(country_node.GetString()) )
        cout << "Invalid country specified at position " << country_node.Offset()?????
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, RapidJSON does not support this in the DOM API.

If you use the SAX API, when you encounter an invalid value, you can return `false` in the handler function, and the `Reader` will generate a `kParseErrorTermination` error with the offset.

The reason why this is not supported in DOM because this will incur memory overhead and may only be used rarely. Please drop an issue at [GitHub](https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson/issues) if you would like to further discuss this feature with the community.